# Spring JPA Query to identify Orphans

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two entities Offer and Candidate; candidate is a child of Offer in a ManyToOne relationship Offer to Candidate.  I need a SpringJPA Query to find all candidates that are not assigned to an offer.  In MySQL I can run

`select * from candidate where candidate.id not in (select candidate_id from offer);`

I've tried variations of `@Query("SELECT DISTINCT candidate FROM Candidate candidate WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT offer from Offer offer")`

Is there an elegant way to craft this query in SpringJPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can run a very similar query in JPQL like what you did in SQL

```java
@Query("SELECT c FROM Candidate c WHERE c.id  NOT IN (SELECT o.candidateId FROM Offer o)")
```